# Does anyone has an experience putting mini-velo into a standard-sized luggage?

Tags: folding-bicycle, bags, transportation, luggage

Personally, I don't trust the designs of many folding bikes mainly because of frame failure issues. So, I am thinking about getting a mini-velo bike, but I wonder if it is possible to fit the bike into a standard-sized luggage.

Comment: Not personally, no.  But the word you're after is "**rinko**" which Japanese-ish for a collapsing bike that can be packed into a suitcase.   The main limiting factor is your wheels, which generally can't shrink, so 20" is a common size.